# How to remove a repository from android studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I made a repository for one of my android projects. But later I deleted that repository from GitHub. Now I made a new repository for that same project. But the previous repository is still showing in the dropdown. Is there any way to make Android Studio completely forget about the first repo?

Comment: Try cleaning Android Studio cache or log out/log in using github credentials

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for doing that is just to delete the previous project from your PC and integrate new repository code in Android Studio.

In that case Android Studio will forget about the first repo and you will be able to work with new repository.